# connecting to linux instance in GCP using external public ip ( client websocket)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

so I am developing a chat application using WebSockets, I created a Linux instance and uploaded the server script to it and run it (it's now waiting for a connection from the client), in the client script I specified the host as the external IP of the VM instance but when I run it, it says

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

this code works on localhost perfectly, I feel I am supposed to do more than just give the external IP of the instance but can't figure out what ( sorry if its a noob question, kinda new to all this )

Comment: It may be firewall.  Are you allowing traffic to the Linux Compute Engine from where the web socket client (browser?) is running?

Comment: umm yes, I think I am, in the source IP filter range its the default value - 0.0.0.0/0 , doing this allows traffic from all IPs right ?

Comment: What about the target port?  Is that opened up?   If you want live chat, find me on GCP slack ... googlecloud-community.slack.com .. user kolban

Comment: yes I am listening on all ports, I'll try on slack

Comment: Besides VPC firewall, do you have a firewall service on Linux enabled? If yes, you should enable incoming connections there as well. Please make sure your application is really listening on the expected port of the Linux server: `netstat -tnlp` or `ss -plnt`.